# How can I simulate transaction ID wraparound in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, transactions, simulation, vacuum

I'm trying to get a better understanding of how XID wraparound affects the results of the query to find the snapshot xmin (that is `txid_snapshot_xmin(txid_current_snapshot())` or `pg_snapshot_xmin(pg_snapshot_current())` after Postgres 13) and the stored `xmin` value in Postgres tuples:

My understanding of XID wraparound is :

1. After 4 billion transactions, the `xmin` value wraps around (starts from 0, 1, 2...). This is internally represented as an `xid`, which is essentially a 32 bit integer.
2. However, the results of `txid_snapshot_xmin(txid_current_snapshot())` or `pg_snapshot_xmin(pg_snapshot_current())`, according to the documentation, return an `xid8` which increases monotonically, and never wraps around. [ref](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-PG-SNAPSHOT)
3. The snapshot value in step 2 has an epoch value associated with it which can be calculated as
   `txid_snapshot_xmin(txid_current_snapshot()) >> 32`. This essentially represents the number of times wraparound has occurred. More importantly, if this value is different from a previous queried value, this means that wraparound has occurred. Conversely, by executing `txid_snapshot_xmin(txid_current_snapshot()) % 2^32` one can get the `xmin` value that would is assigned to a row (the 32-bit value)

I'm trying to simulate this behavior to verify my theory, but I don't currently have access to a high volume database (with > 4 billion transactions).

Is there a good way to simulate a large volume of transactions on a test DB to see this wraparound in action? That is, without actually executing 4B transactions?

I'm thinking that *maybe* there is some internal state/counter of the current number of transaction that I can modify, but I haven't had any luck with this.

Answer (score 3):

It is difficult to simulate transaction ID wraparound. There are efforts to do that for the PostgreSQL regression tests, but that is work in progress.

You may find [my article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/transaction-id-wraparound-a-walk-on-the-wild-side/) interesting. The trick used there is to artificially advance the transaction ID with

```bash
pg_resetwal -x 123456789 -D datadir
```

Your understanding is mostly correct, but the critical point for wraparound is 2<sup>31</sup> transactions, because that is the point where low transaction IDs change over from the distant past to the remote future.

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful, I will go through this